# React-Native using Multiple Java Classes

Tags: java, android, react-native, bluetooth

I've developed a Java(Android) bunch of classes that deal with [Bluetooth Connection](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth)(not BLE) because React Native does not have it implemented. And since it's easier develop interface with react-native I want to use my java classes inside my react-native application.

I already did a example using the [Toast Example from documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android) and it worked, but my question is related not about one method but every method related to it.

So, to "expose" a java method to react native is pretty simple, but what I want is make sure that it will execute **everything** correctly:

```java
//ClassA methodA
@ReactMethod
  public void methodA() {
       ClassB classB = new ClassB();
       classB.methodB();
  }
//ClassB methodB
  private void methodB(){
        ClassC classC = new ClassC();
        classC.methodC();
  }
//ClassC methodC
  private void methodC(){
        //Start thread
  }
```

So, let's say it is three classes in java, Class A, B, C and they have also some dependencies between each other and some of them extends Thread class to better performance, my question is:

1. I'll have to expose every method that is executed or just the root method?
2. React-native can handle android classes that extends a Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to expose methods that are directly called by your javascript.  Methods that are only called indirectly by other Java functions should not be annotated as a ReactMethod.

WHat do you mean by "handle android classes that extends a Thread?"  Are you asking can you launch a thread?  Yes, but if you want to wait for the thread to finish and plan on await-ing for the result in JS you'll have to handle the promise work in the thread yourself.  Also remember that all ReactMethods are called asynchronously on a thread not the main thread.

Comment: Got it! Just another question, the maven dependencies from my classes will be imported on react-native? Is there any preparation before? Like a mvn install?

Comment: If you're using a standard Android Studio gradle build, there are no preconditions needed.  Just run gradlew with the right parametetrs (or hit the build button in Android Studio, which does that for you).  It will grab any dependencies listed in build.gradle and cache them for next time.

Comment: Great! Thanks Gabe!